# Magento 2: Trying to change fonts. Changes not being affected on live site

Tags: magento2

I am trying to change the font on a Magento 2 site from MarkWebPro to Bitner. I have uploaded the Bitner files to the fonts folder and made the following changes:

mytheme/web/scss/source/_typography.less

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Bitner',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Bitner/Bitner-Regular',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal
)

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Bitner',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Bitner/Bitner-Italic',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: italic
)

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Bitner',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Bitner/Bitner-Bold',
    @font-weight: bold,
    @font-style: normal
)

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Bitner',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Bitner/Bitner-BoldItalic',
    @font-weight: bold,
    @font-style: italic
)

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Bitner',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Bitner/Bitner-Medium',
    @font-weight: 500,
    @font-style: normal
)

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'Bitner',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Bitner/Bitner-MediumItalic',
    @font-weight: 500,
    @font-style: italic
)
etc..
```

mytheme/web/scss/source/_variables.less

```
//changed from "@font-family-name__base: 'MarkWebPro';"
@font-family-name__base: 'Bitner';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
etc..
```

I removed the pub/static folder then deployed by running the command "./magento setup:static-content:deploy", it ran a while and everything was successful. I then went into the Magento dashboard and flushed the Magento cache and also cleared my browser's cache.

Unfortunately, the font change is not showing. I have gone to the website in incognito mode and in a different browser and every page is still using the original MarkWebPro font for all text. Any help would be deeply appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I did everything correctly. I waited a few days and went back to the page and the new font was showing correctly. I don't know why it took so long to reflect the changes, maybe there's some kind of caching on my server that I'm not aware of.

Comment: It might have been a browser cache issue.  I've definitely had some of those where flushing the magento cache wasn't enough and flushing my browser cache was needed to see the changes.

Comment: @MikeLevy I did wipe my browser cache, visited the page in incognito mode, and also visited it on a different device but the change wasn't being shown that same day. Very strange.